# Game Kit with iOS6

Tags: uiviewcontroller, game-center, ios6

I recently tried to authenticate the local user on iOS 6 with the new iOS 6 method, and it returns in the authenticate handler-

```
localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error)
```

How do I display this view controller? (FYI- GC automatically dismisses the window when completed authenticating the local player)

I'm using storyboard in the project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Once you set the handler, it will be called at different situations. In those calls, the viewController parameter can be nil or it can actually be an instance GKHostedAuthenticateViewController.

**You need to check if the viewController is not nil, and in that case, you can display it as you would do with any other view controller.**

Here you have some sample code from the Game Center Programming guide

```
- (void) authenticateLocalPlayer
{
    GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error){
         if (viewController != nil)
         {
             [self showAuthenticationDialogWhenReasonable: viewController
         }
         else if (localPlayer.isAuthenticated)
         {
             [self authenticatedPlayer: localPlayer];
         }
         else
         {
             [self disableGameCenter];
         }
     }];
}
```

Check out the [GKLocalPlayer Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKLocalPlayer_Ref/Reference/Reference.html) and the [Game Center Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Users/Users.html)